# Summing Values of Cells of Certain Font Color in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with cells that contain numbers styled with fonts of different colors. I would like to sum all cell values of a certain color and output that sum into a separate cell. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you consider using google app script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (B1 contains a checkbox)

```
=sumColor(A:A,B1)
```

- put the formula in a range with the **same color** as the data to be added
- add a **check box** to allow you updating the value when colors will be changed
- the formula **can be located in another sheet**

with this custom function

```
function sumColor(range) {
  var r = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var color = r.getFontColors();
  var total = 0;
  var addresses = r.getFormula().match(/(?<=\().*(?=\))/g)[0].split(/[;|,]/)
  for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length - 1 ; i++) {
    try {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getSheetByName(addresses[i].split('!')[0].replace("'", ""));
      var address = addresses[i].split('!')[1].trim();
    }
    catch (e) {
      var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var address = addresses[i].trim()
    }
    var colors = sh.getRange(address).getFontColors();
    var values = sh.getRange(address).getValues();
    for (var j = 0; j < colors.length; j++)
      for (var k = 0; k < colors[i].length; k++)
        if (colors[j][k] == color)
          if ((typeof values[j][k]) == 'number') 
            total += values[j][k];
  }
  return total;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How would I modify `getBackgrounds` to have it working for font colors instead? Also, where do I add the custom formula?

Comment: I apologize, I have corrected the answer.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I get a syntactic error. My range is 2D. Could that be the difference? I am also not sure what the checkbox does and where I should put it in my case.

Comment: This also works for 2D array. However, the 1D or 2D range must be continuous. The color between the ranges and the result must be exactly the same. Can you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Here is a test table that looks very much like the one I have. I am trying to use colors to have the sheet visually encode and automatically compute how much each person has on-hand. Those amount are located in the upper right-hand corner.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15mvCyITb-jvb-PGd0tUtz2Pppnvs48vuKhXd_DmFN_4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Russia means you must use a semicolon instead of a comma in the formula. Then you have to colorize the cell with the same color... take a look at the spreadsheet that I corrected.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Who would have thought that formulas worked differently, based on locale :/ Are there any other differences?

Comment: Could you tell me how I can get it to sum all values in the 2D table? That is, it currently sums just one column. I would like to get all values of that color in the entire 2D table and add them up. I have tried that in cell R5, but it seems incorrect. Or I am not understanding how it treats the color.

Comment: Change the font color of R5 and check in N5 to re-calculate

Comment: Everything seems to be working now, and I understand your logic! Thank you! :-)